# Need to set Global variable

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt1.0.I want to use a global variable such a way that, the value of variable is set from one template and used in another template..How can i achieve this.
Please help me..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vTest">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/element"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$vTest"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML input:

```
<t>
    <element>A</element>
    <element>B</element>
    <element>C</element>
</t>
```

Result:

```
ABC
```

**Note:** $vTest with a value template will be [RTF](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) in 1.0. But for this case it can be used like as of string data-type.

Comment: +1 Because it follows exactly the question text (although I think the intention was some kind of side effect variable...). A minor: `xsl:value-of` will get the string value of the XPath expression by the `string()` function invocation.

Comment: @Alejandro, what I meant is that variable content in this case can be treated as string. No accent on how exactly it is done.

Comment: I think the discussion is deviating my objective.Let me make my question more clear.. 

<w:tc>
   first
</w:tc>

<w:tc>
   second
</w:tc>
This is my input.

<xsl:template match="tc">
<!-- When the first match occurs, i am setting a value for a global variable and when the template matches for second time, i have to fetch the value from that variable -->
</xsl:template>